# How can I position two views on opposite sides of a superview using Auto Layout's visual format language?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

Currently I'm using Auto Layout's visual format language to horizontally position these views like so:

H:|-[Label]-[Button]-|

The problem is the spacing in between the label and button. How does one make this space flexible so that the Label is always aligned with the left side of the superview, and the Button with the right side of the superview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tell autolayout to set a space that is >=0 like so:

```
  @"H:|-[Label]-(>=0)-[Button]-|"
```